# Twitter Bootstrap Div centering issue within a full-width container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The layout is seems very simple however troubleshooting seems to be beyond my css and bootrstap skills -

I am trying to have a full-width div with a gradient background - #topwrapper, which will then hold another div of fixed dimensions (span12 = 1170px) centered - #headerimage. The goal is to have the #headerimage div scaled as tghe browser is resized.

Issue is, that for some unknown reason the #headerimage get pushed to the left instead of being centered.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container" id="topwrapper">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12" id="headerimage">PLEASE CENTER</div>
   </div>
</div>

#topwrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:270px;
    background:url(../img/tophead-wrapper-bg.png) repeat transparent;   
}

#headerimage {
    background:url(../img/thbg01.jpg) no-repeat transparent;   
    height:270px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

And here is the link to the page in question:
http://kh.kagyu.org. Disregard anything below the red bar

Anyone knows the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fluid layout, you need to use the class `container-fluid` instead of just `container`.(Make sure you are including the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file in your project)

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="topwrapper">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12" id="headerimage">PLEASE CENTER</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want a fixed layout, then remove the `-fluid` from both the `container` and the `row`.

```
<div class="container" id="topwrapper">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span12" id="headerimage">PLEASE CENTER</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Add `text-align:center` to center the text. You can remove the `margin: 0 auto;`, if you are using the `span12` class, the div will be centered by the bootstrap grid system.

```
#headerimage {
    background:url(../img/thbg01.jpg) no-repeat transparent;   
    height:270px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the container class adds margin and width centering whatever you have in it, the correct way to do this would be the following layout, the text-center class adds text-align:center therefore centering your image, hope it helps!

```
<div id="topwrapper">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12 text-center" id="headerimage">PLEASE CENTER</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```